# Firefox focus to first input after focus out a button

Tags: jquery, firefox, tabs, indexing, focus

I try to manipulate the focus after the user leave a button on a form. After leaving the focus should be set to the first input of the form. But it does not working with Firefox. The focus goes first to the current tab, than to the address bar and after that to the first input. Any ideas how to fix that? If I set an alert after focus in focusout I see that the first input field has the focus for a short time. Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input name="input1" tabindex="1"/>
        <input name="input2" tabindex="2"/>
        <button name="button" class="button" tabindex="3">Button</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input:first').focus();                
            $('.button').focusout(function(){
                $('input:first').focus();
            });
        });
    </script>       
</body>
```